# Clarification for ptr and @data

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I'm trying to learn Assembly and a few questions showed up,
I want to be sure that all the things I learned are clear for me, so;

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
var1 db 50
var2 db 150
sum dw 0
CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    ;------------
    mov ax, 0
    add sum, [word ptr var1]
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

@data - As far as I know, the assembler defines it and his value is the address of the first variable of the data segment. which used as a pointer for the DS register. 
So what will DS contain if I'm not using it?

Secondly, I tried to sum the var1 and var2, after I google it, I learned that "[word ptr var1]" will not convert var1 which is one-byte to two-byte, it just relates it as two-byte, which means the value will be "50150" according to the code above. And still, if it relates it as two-byte size and sum is also two-byte size, why I get this error: [image]

exit label - Should I call for it or it automatically will be called when the start label is complete? and if so, how?

Thanks in advance, hope that you understand my questions and sorry for my English.
*Btw, if there is a better title for this post, feel free to ask me for a change it for future users with the same questions.

Comment: 1) `DS` has some value always. For DOS I think it points to the PSP by default 2) you need to convert it by using `movzx` or `movsx` for unsigned or signed, respectively. E.g. `movzx dx, [var1]; add [sum], dx`. You could also load `al` and rely on `ah` being zero so `mov al, [var1]; add [sum], ax` 3) you can't use two memory operands for `add` and you need brackets for memory operands 4) execution is continuous so the `exit` block will be processed automatically

Comment: By the way, you wouldn't get 50150 if you read those two bytes as a word; you'd get 38450 (`(150 << 8) | 50`).

Comment: @Jester 1) From where DS gets his values if I didn't declare on it? other programs that used those addresses and what is PSP? 
2) Thanks, the second one is a nice logical trick.
3) Ohh, I just realized that both of them are memory addresses, it makes sense, thanks!
4) Thanks!


btw Michael, I tried to do "mov ax, 0; add ax, [word ptr var1]" and the ax register changed to 9632, which make sense since that is how those numbers look like as hex, so I don't really understand what you said :\

Comment: The OS loads your program, it allocates the memory for it. [PSP is the program segment prefix, some metadata for your program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix). `DS` is set up to point there. As for the `9632` that is in hex. In decimal, that is indeed `38450` as Michael said.